# Merge-sorting a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, mergesort

I'm required to sort a Linked list using merge sort. I've put together this code, but I'm running into a weird error.

My linked list is populated by random numbers. However, after sorting, it only displays numbers that are larger than the first element of the linked list, in sorted order.

Here is some of my code:

```
node* MergeSort(node *my_node)
{
    node *secondNode;

    if (my_node == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (my_node->next == NULL)
        return my_node;
    else
    {
        secondNode = Split(my_node);
        return Merge(MergeSort(my_node),MergeSort(secondNode));
    }
}

node* Merge(node* firstNode, node* secondNode)
{
    if (firstNode == NULL) return secondNode;
    else if (secondNode == NULL) return firstNode;
    else if (firstNode->number <= secondNode->number) //if I reverse the sign to >=, the behavior reverses
    {
        firstNode->next = Merge(firstNode->next, secondNode);
        return firstNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        secondNode->next = Merge(firstNode, secondNode->next);
        return secondNode;
    }
}

node* Split(node* my_node)
{
    node* secondNode;

    if (my_node == NULL) return NULL;
    else if (my_node->next == NULL) return NULL;
    else {
        secondNode = my_node->next;
        my_node->next = secondNode->next;
        secondNode->next = Split(secondNode->next);
        return secondNode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code and it works perfectly.

Have you looked at the right list in the end?
Your new head of the list is not the previous head, but the return value of
the Merge function.

```
printList(myList);
node* sortedList =  MergeSort(myList);
printList(sortedList); //whole list sorted
printList(myList); //list (of elements not smaller that first element) sorted
```

and printList() is the obvious function:

```
void printList(node* my_node){
    if(my_node == NULL) return;
    else {
        std::cout<<my_node->number<<" "<<std::endl; 
        printList(my_node->next);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I see where I was going wrong. Thanks. This fixed it.